# Is changing an object's variable outside of the object considered a side effect?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, side-effects

I'm trying to understand functional vs object-oriented programming. What I'm currently trying to understand is this notion of side effects in object-oriented programming, particularly as it pertains to increasing the security of a program.

I understand a "side-effect" as anything that changes the variables linked to one function within an object that are used by a different function used by an object. But what about allowing the setting of object variables outside of the object but not within a function inside of the object.

Seems to me like this would be safer than having it be set within another function. And functions within that object that use this variable would know that no other function will change it without notice.

Am I missing something? Would you still consider this to be a side effect?  What about setting a bunch of variables upon the initialization of the object?

Comment: *anything* a function does that has an observable effect on anything else in the program - or the "outside world" - is considered a side effect. The only useful things that functions can do apart from side effects is take arguments and return a result based on them. In other words a calculation of some sort. And while that seems really limiting when you're not used to functional programming, a language like Haskell proves that you can indeed write most of most programs with pure functions and limit side effects to just a few places where they're absolutely necessary.

Comment: So yes, altering the value of a variable in a function is a side effect, at least when that variable can be read from outside the function - like instance variables in OOP. Haskell gets around this by essentially having no mutable variables at all, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Where are places that side effects absolutely necessary?

Comment: Places where it can't avoid interacting with the outside world. Eg outputting text/graphics to a screen, interacting with a database, or files, or making network requests, etc

Answer (score 5):

A side effect is anything that lets you *observe* a difference in program behavior based on *whether*, *how many times*, or *in what order* an expression is evaluated or action is executed, that is, breaking [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). Mutating variables is one example of a side effect, but so is sending a message on a concurrent channel, printing to the terminal, writing to a file, or reading from the network.

It’s the *observability* from within normal safe code that makes something side-effectful; Haskell’s runtime uses mutable variables all the time for lazy evaluation, but you can’t *see* that from within the language without unsafe code. If it’s *possible* to observe the effect with respect to the context you’re in, it’s still a side effect. So what you describe (restricting who can mutate fields of an object) sounds maybe *safer*, but it’s not side-effect–free.

For example, `Debug.Trace.trace :: String -> a -> a` has a side effect when *evaluated* because `trace "x" (1 :: Int) + trace "x" (1 :: Int)` is observably different from `let x = trace "x" (1 :: Int) in x + x`:

```
> trace "x" (1 :: Int) + trace "x" (1 :: Int)
x
x
2

> let x = trace "x" (1 :: Int) in x + x
x
2
```

`modifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO ()` has a side effect when *executed* because modifying a mutable reference multiple times is clearly different from modifying it only once:

```
increment :: IORef Int -> IO ()
increment r = modifyIORef r (+ 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do

  r1 <- newIORef 0
  increment r1
  print =<< readIORef r1  -- 1

  r2 <- newIORef 0
  increment r2
  increment r2
  print =<< readIORef r2  -- 2
```

(But note that a value of type `IO a` for some `a` *is* pure when *evaluated*: it’s *not* a value of type `a` “tagged” with the fact that it came from I/O; rather, it’s a *program* or *action* that *returns* a value of type `a` when hooked up to `main` and executed by the runtime.)

Note that not all *effectful* code is *side-effectful*: `pure () :: IO ()` is in `IO` but clearly has no side effects. Likewise, `ST` provides *local* mutable variables that are guaranteed not to escape or be visible outside their scope, so you can implement a pure function that’s impure internally:

```
pureSum :: Int -> Int
pureSum n = sum [1 .. n]

impureSum :: Int -> IO Int
impureSum n = do
  result <- newIORef 0
  for_ [1 .. n] $ \ x -> do
    putStrLn ("Adding " ++ show x)  -- Side effect!
    modifyIORef result (+ x)
  readIORef result

internallyImpureSum :: Int -> Int
internallyImpureSum = runST $ do
  result <- newSTRef 0

  for_ [1 .. n] $ \ x -> do
    -- Can’t perform any side effects observable outside.
    modifySTRef result (+ x)

  -- Can *read* the reference, but returning
  -- the reference ‘result’ itself would be
  -- a type error.
  readSTRef result
```

As for “setting a bunch of variables upon initialization of the object”, that’s basically the pattern used in Haskell, not only to help enforce safety, but as a mathematically inspired philosophy of data modelling in general.

In OOP languages, the convention for modelling changing state is to create a *single* object, which has a notion of identity, and modify it over time using commands or direct mutation. An object is expected to remain valid by *maintaining* all its invariants for every state change.

Whereas in Haskell, the convention is that an object is an immutable *snapshot* or *representation* of the state, and you can model a changing state by simply creating a new value to represent the new state. If you no longer need the old one, just forget it and let it be garbage-collected. An object doesn’t need to *maintain* any invariants after construction, because it’s immutable: it just needs to *enforce* the invariants *once* when it’s constructed. This can be done with precise data modelling with algebraic data types (a.k.a. “making illegal states unrepresentable”), or using encapsulation and smart constructor functions to prevent invalid values from being constructed (a.k.a. “correctness by construction”).

Comment: I don't think "once vs. multiple" is a good definition of a side effect. An idempotent effect would not be considered an effect under this definition.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: Good point. I guess I was thinking of “*zero*, one, or many”. I rephrased a bit, but it’s hard to find a good pithy explanation of what I mean. Basically, I think “side effects” *always* depend on a context of observation. In a pure `State`/`ST` action, `modify`/`modifySTRef` is a SE *inside* a common `runState`/`runST` (since the whole point is that subsequent actions can see the change), but not *outside* that context; likewise, `putStrLn "hi"` is a SE *within* `IO`, but pure from the POV of safe Haskell as a purely functional metalanguage for *constructing* `IO` programs.

Comment: If you work in an impure setting one of the first things you notice is losing idempotency in a lot of cases. I think this argument is still legitimate even though it doesn't hold for all classes of side effects. Another less technical explanation is that side effects introduce time. I might be wrong on this but I think the associative law is the most important one that enforces the absence of time in FP. So side effects interfere with associativity.

Answer (score 1):

A side effect can be any change to observable state; "inside" vs. "outside" the function isn't a useful or well-defined qualifier for this purpose.

Consider the `static` local variable in C, which creates a global variable accessible to that function.  The problem is that the function can be called from anywhere, in any thread.  It doesn't matter whether you consider the variable "inside" the function or not:  if the function can read and update the static variable, it is not re-entrant, due to the side-effect.

The danger of the side-effect is that it is hidden from the programmer.  If the observable state is clear to the programmer, then you could argue that it's "just an effect, not a side-effect".  For example, a C++ non-const method is expected to be able to update the state of its object.  Every time you call the method, you need to provide a target object for it to update;  this kind of effect is not as hazardous as the static variable because the observable state is evident (rather than "off to the side").  However, you can still get in trouble due to aliasing:  e.g., if one of the parameters to the method happens to be another reference to the target object...

To some extent "side effect" is also relative to what you have chosen to consider important.  For example, you could run a pure function in a debugger, and set a breakpoint.  Is the function then less pure because it can print a stack trace on your screen?  That depends on whether you think that's important (in this case, "probably not").